# What's an efficient way to retrieve chat messages from Realm?

Tags: java, android, database, realm, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to create a chat app, therefore both tokens and topics are being used. In my application I've created a POJO which extends RealmObject intended for storing the chat messages from different userIDs as well as the ones I've sent, both in private-chats and groups. 
But what I can't understand is, how should I frame the Realm Query to retrieve the received messages and the messages I've sent to a UserID.

I'm thinking of trying:

```
RealmResults<ChatModel> results=mDatabase.where(TestChatModel.class)
                                .equalTo("sender",<Person with whom Im chatting's userID >)
                                .or()
                                .equalTo("receiver",<Person with whom Im chatting's userID >)
                                .and()
                                .equalTo("sender",<My userID >)
                                .or()
                                .equalTo("receiver",<My userID >
                                .sort("timestamp")
                                .findAll();
```

But that just seems very inefficient and messed up.

My POJO is:

```
public class TestChatModel {
    private String chatMessage;
    private String timestamp;
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String topicName; // Set to NA is private-chat
    private int isTopic;      // Set to 0 for private-chat and Set to 1 for 
                              // group
.
.
.
//Associated constructors and getters and setters
.
.
}
```

The community's help is much appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine. All you can do is write down the query logic and then translate in into Realm query syntax. If your intention is to create a query with the criteria being that:

1. A specific person is either the sender or receiver, AND
2. The logged in user either the sender or receiver

Then that's probably the best way to do it. This assumes that you have ALL messages to and from everyone in the Realm; if you were to apply some other rule (e.g. that you only have messages including the logged in user in the Realm) then you could ditch clause 2, as this would be implied. An example of this would be if your API only provided messages for a logged in user (which seems like a reasonable scenario). That would improve efficiency and simplify the query.

In terms of other ways to improve efficiency, it's likely (although I have no direct evidence) that using a numerical ID for users rather than a string ID would allow for more efficient comparison and filtering in Realm. This would be preferable, but may depend on your API (again).

Finally, it's probably worth adding 'parentheses' to your query if it remains as above to ensure the operators are evaluated as you expect (i.e. the AND in the middle of the ORs). This can be accomplished with `beginGroup` and `endGroup` in the query (as described [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#logical-operators)).